# How does this SQL syntax work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across this horrifyingly freakish SQL query today that another developer generated with the SQL Server query designer tool.  *I hate the query designer, but I'm stuck trying to figure out what it did.*  I've never seen syntax like it before and don't understand it.  How does it work?

In particular it is is the multiple ON clauses joined together separate from the JOIN clauses that is throwing me off.

```
SELECT *
FROM  dbo.tblDealStatus
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblUser
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblOwnerLocation
                     INNER JOIN dbo.tblOwner
                          INNER JOIN dbo.tblDeal
                           ON dbo.tblOwner.OwnerID = dbo.tblDeal.OwnerID
                      ON dbo.tblOwnerLocation.DealID = dbo.tblDeal.DealID
             ON dbo.tblUser.UserID = dbo.tblDeal.CHK_Contact
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCompany AS tblCompany_1
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblParticipation
                     ON tblCompany_1.CompanyID = dbo.tblParticipation.CompanyID
             ON dbo.tblDeal.ParticipationID = dbo.tblParticipation.ParticipationID
     ON /*...
      ....so on and so forth...*/
```

Comment: My best guess is that the different `on` statements apply to each respective `join`--ie the first `right outer join` is `ON dbo.tblOwner.OwnerID = dbo.tblDeal.OwnerID`, the second is `ON dbo.tblOwnerLocation.DealID = dbo.tblDeal.DealID`, etc. It's because of stuff like this that I generally dislike and don't use query designer tools or ORMs.

Comment: Does this code even run?  I tried something like this and it does not seem to work on SQL Server 2008

Comment: @AbeMiessler - Yes SQL Server supports it. The tables referenced in each `ON` clause need to be in scope though (What Itzik Ben Gan calls a chiastic relationship)

Comment: Whoever wrote this code needs a beat-down. Oh wait, it was the Query Designer? Yep, that definitely needs a beat-down and people need to stop using it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I've been saying that for 13 years.  Hasn't had much impact though ... :-(

Comment: Personally I'd fire anyone I found using QUery designer for more than the occasional non-production query. Using it regularly means you are incompentent.

Comment: @HLGEM - I couldn't agree more.  I'm not in the best of moods the moment.  ;)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Amen

Comment: Love the edit Jordan ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I make it rule for clarity to never mix right and left joins in the same query. All right joins can be switched to left joins and that alone will make it easier to figure out what is going on.

Next abandon select *. It is never appropraite in a query with joins as you are returning the same data in two or more fields (the join fields) and that is wasteful of valuable network and database processing time.

I believe the wierd ONs are forcing the query to go in a particular order. They are bad and should not be used in my opinion as they are hard to maintain and hard for developers to understand as they are not common and are totally unneeded.  Just reversing the right joins and putting the tables in the order you need to join them may fix this. If not you may need a few derived tables to get the right data. Note that in reversing it, you may need to change those inner joins to something else. Right now it is such a mess, it is highly likely it does not return the correct results. So in rewriting it, while you would want to see if your changes change the results, you would also want to use judgement to determine if the changes are fixes for a bad query or incorrect changes to translate the query into something maintainable.

If the developer who wrote this mess is still there, I would force him to rewrite in in more standard SQL and tell him he is forbidden to ever use the query designer again. This fails code review as far as I am concerned.

If I were rewriting this, I would look for the table that should be first in the query and work down from there. My personal guess right now is that it would be the tblDeal table but I don't know your data model so I could be wrong.

Comment: +1 for 'do not mix LOJ and ROJ in single query'.